# Verify the size of an file and if it is bigger then X empty it

Tags: c#

I would like to verify the size of a folder and if it is bigger then 2 gb i should empty it . How can i do so ?

Comment: you'd tell us what language/tools you want to use, java, python, bash?

Comment: What do you mean empty it? Delete it? Recycle the bits?

Comment: Why does this feel like you are just keeping a log file down to size? In which case just use log4net or similar, don't re-invent the wheel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx) property of the [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class to get the file size, then truncate the file with [WriteAllText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx) or similar:

```
using System.IO;

if (new FileInfo(yourFilePath).Length > Int32.MaxValue) {
    File.WriteAllText(yourFilePath, String.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo("path to file");
            if (f.Length > 2147483648)
                File.Delete("path to file");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\test.txt");
if (fInfo.Length> 2147483648)
{ 
  File.WriteAllText(fInfo.FullName, "");
}
```